# How to disable screen off in Debian?

Tags: debian, screensaver, xscreensaver

My screen are darkening every 20 or some minutes. It was originally xscreensaver installed, but nothing changed after I removed it. This behavior very annoying when I am trying to see some movie.

There is output of `xset q`:

```
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  0    cycle:  0
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 7200    Suspend: 7200    Off: 14400
  DPMS is Disabled
```

I have tried to disable DMPS by `xset -dpms` but it looks like something reenables it time-to-time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by usage of XFCE's power managment GUI configurator

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the output of `xset q`, it will tell you if DPMS is enabled, and the times to suspend.

You switch it off completely with `xset -dpms`, or set the times with `

```
xset dpms <standby_seconds> <suspend_seconds> <off_seconds>
```

You can also configure it in the `ServerFlags` section in your `xorg.conf`, see `man xorg.conf`.

Many player applications (e.g. `mplayer`) automatically disable dpms it while playing a movie.

Comment: It doesn't help. Nor disabling DPMS, nor settings in VLC player.

Comment: Please edit question with output of `xset q`, the parts in `Screen Saver` and in `DPMS`.

Answer (score 1):

On Debian 11 XFCE (22sep2022) I can disable screensaver using cmd `xfce4-settings-manager`. This CLI command starts a GUI and in "Power Manager" choose tab "Display." You will have two tabs: "On Battery" and "Plugged In".

You've probably been here already trying to stop the dang screensaver, but avoid making it faster by sliding the time to the left.

No, some genius decided that at 0, the scrensaver was not permanently ON, no, it becomes OFF. So slide all the times to 0 on both tabs.

On battery:

> [image: on battery]

On AC power:

> [image: on ac power]

Answer (score 0):

Working with the same problem since connecting with x0vncserver on the remote host and vncviewer at local host, yields a black screen when screensaver is activated.

Seems you also need to turn off the setting for security
within the power manager settings of xfce4-settings-manager to completely turn off the screensaver in xfce4.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).